# Materialize mobile nav bar not responding

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm using Materialize with a Rails project and I'm not sure why the collapsible nav bar transformations aren't responding.

_nav.html.erb

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="/" class="brand-logo center">LOGO</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_session_path(current_user) if current_user %></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_session_path(current_user) if current_user %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

community.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
)};
```

Right now if I shrink the viewport and click the mobile menu button, the screen gets a grey overlay but the actual sidebar itself won't appear. I inspected the elements and compared my version to the demo version on the Materialize website and it looks like for whatever reason certain CSS components are rendering incorrectly on my side.

First in the  tag, the width isn't adjusting on my side.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icMV6.png)

Second, the  style on my side is appearing as left while the original Materialize version is coming up as transform. [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6hnZ.png)

I didn't modify any of the css aside from changing the font-family. It was working a couple days ago but now it doesn't. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was calling in the Materialize.min.js file from cdnjs. When I switched to using the inminified version (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js) everything worked perfectly.